# TabError in Python 3 function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im writing a new program for my friend,
 and in a function I have a try and an except but if i run it, it gives me
 an error :"File "main.py", line 19
    try:
       ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"
 Im trying everything to fix it but it doesn't work...

Comment: well what is not clear about the error?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem so i don't understand how i can get this tab error, it's the same column as the other things in the function, and they don't get an TabError

Comment: @FelixEckert: well that means that on that specific line, you probably used other space/tab patterns. Usually an editor displays a tab as for instance four spaces. So it is hard to see the difference, but there is something different with that line.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is fairly self-explanatory: `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation` simply means that you are using tabs in some places in your code and spaces in other places.

This can be a little difficult to diagnose as although two lines will *appear* to be the same level of indentation, one will be indented with a tab and the other with probably 3 or 4 spaces.

The reason this is important in Python, is that as I am sure you are aware, scopes are defined using indentation. So if you are not consistently using either tabs or spaces (as you most likely are), a `TabError` will be thrown!

If you are still unsure where you have used spaces instead of tabs (or the other way around), most text-editors will have the option to show white-space and tab allowing you to easily see where you've slipped up.

Answer (score -1):

It is indeed very hard to distinguish spaces and tabs by our human beings! However, you can use **Python IDLE GUI (in Windows)** to **Tabify** (under Format) the whole file to make sure the indentation is consistent.